# Mirror copies of redo logs

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-asm, transaction-log

I'm running an two node RAC database with ASM having two DGs one for data and one for redo. I have only one copy of redo and I have the need to have another copy of redo logs.
1. How to go ahead with adding mirror copies of redo? 
2. Will it demand downtime? 
3. Can I add the copies which I'm going to create in the data DG?
4. I also need to create a copy for the control file. How can I do that as well?

Thanks,
Tesla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need downtime just to add additional redo logs to your redo groups.

Take a look at this:

[Oracle Configuration Best Practices](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10726/configbp.htm#1006950)

And then look at this:

[Creating Redo Log Groups and Members](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10739/onlineredo.htm#i1006398)

You will need downtime to add additional control files:

[Creating Additional Copies, Renaming, and Relocating Control Files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/control003.htm#i1006277)